# Error when opening simulator with iOS 8 beta

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have recently installed Xcode 6 beta in OS X Mavericks, with which comes the iOS simulator for iOS 8.

using this new Xcode I have create one new project and run it on simulator with iOS 8, but when opening the simulator, it always get the error

> Unable to boot the iOS Simulator

So, pls tell me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Quit both the simulator and Xcode. If that doesn't fix it, reboot your Mac.

Welcome to the world of beta builds!

Comment: If you launch the Simulator manually and "Reset Content and Settings" in the application menu, does that help?

Comment: I also try this way, but at that time display error "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator"

Comment: If you launch Console.app (in /Application/Utilities) do you get any logging output there that might shed some light on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you "select" your new Xcode version before launching / downloading updates.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer/
```

If you're already seeing Simulator troubles, try rebooting too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you load X-Code 6 and not 5.
2. Run your project.
3. If fails to load, try clicking on the menu at the top on the iOS Simulator button and reset the device. Resetting the device seems to do the trick for me.

Also, make sure you are on the laatst x-code version